# How to create language for microsoft speech recognizer

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

I am developing a Speech Recognition Application in C# by using Microsoft Speech API. 
I need a speech recognizer for the following language :

- uz-Latn-UZ

The Speech Recognition Language does not exists for this language. So I wanna create my own Lightweight Speech Recognition Language for this language.

How can i do this?

Comment: Adding language in ASR is a huge effort, unless you contact Microsoft there is no hope for that. You can create an ASR system with [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net), it has all the tools for training the speech recognition systems in new language. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202698/writing-speech-recognition-engine and http://asmp.eurasipjournals.com/content/pdf/1687-4722-2011-426795.pdf