# Library for speech recognition which supports Punjabi language?

Tags: visual-c++, speech-recognition

I want to develop a speech recognition system for punjabi language, but I am not able to find any library supporting Punjabi language and having efficient use.

Answer (score 0):

You can build and use acoustic models for CMUSphinx

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

See for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215967/432021

Comment: as i am a new user and it will take a lot of time to add punjabi language in it. so can u plz suggest some already built library for this purpose. But if its not possible then can u give some idea how to do this.