# speech recognition in C# for urdu language

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

Please correct me if i am wrong actually i am beginner developer. I want to write a speech recognition algorithm for my university project. I want to write speech recognition algorithm for urdu language. Till is it in my mind is that first i should create a urdu grammar. then train the speech recognition engine then detect the word. 
what i have tried yet...!

- I have written speech recognition algorithm for english.
- I have written 2 words grammar to recognize.

That algorithm is working. So what i should change in the algorithm for recognizing urdu language or to create a urdu grammar. Please guide me where to start.

```
static void RecognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou()
    {
        _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("hello computer"))); // load a "hello computer" grammar
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou_SpeechRecognized; // if speech is recognized, call the specified method
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognitionRejected += _recognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input to the default audio device
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous
    }
    static void _recognizeSpeechAndMakeSureTheComputerSpeaksToYou_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == "testing")
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer speechSynthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            speechSynthesizer.Speak("test completed");
            speechSynthesizer.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you will need to make a new grammar engine(or reconfigure the one for english), and after that you should be able to continue how ever you did to get english working and it should work perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Speech doesn't support Urdu language. And you can't add your own language to the engine. You need to start building your own speech recognition engine. It's a huge task.
If you want how to start, you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202698/writing-speech-recognition-engine).

Comment: Is there any way to change the pronunciation of microsoft speech recognition grammar?

Comment: You mean you change something, than you speak an Urdu word and MS Speech recognize it as an English word?  It's impossible.

Comment: Yes..!! Just want to trying that way. If i change the pronunciation style then may be MS speech recognize any word.